# Mac OS X goes to sleep mode when watching video or suddenly restarts

Tags: catalina, sleep-wake, video

Mac OS X Catalina goes to sleep right after I start watching video/youtube.
I also can hear how its fan's extensively working.
It started after I installed MineCraft, but this maybe just a coincidence as it's going to sleep mode only when watching a vide.
But right after it's in sleep mode when I push a power button it wakes up with no fan's noise.

I even did a recovery on the OS, the issue remains.

I looked at other SO threads but they were not helpful.

Not sure if this is Catalina's issue or not...

Just wanted to know is there's anything I should try before I decide to downgrade the OS.

**UPDATE**

I had to delete my answer as I discovered the issue remains.
Also I noticed random restarts. After I restart I see these message in the report:

> Mac OS version: 19E287
>
> Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 19.4.0: Wed Mar  4 22:28:40 PST
>   2020; root:xnu-6153.101.6~15/RELEASE_X86_64 Kernel UUID:
>   AB0AA7EE-3D03-3C21-91AD-5719D79D7AF6 Kernel slide:
>   0x0000000004400000 Kernel text base: 0xffffff8004600000
>   __HIB  text base: 0xffffff8004500000 System model name: iMac15,1 (Mac-FA842E06C61E91C5) System shutdown begun: NO Panic diags file
>   available: YES (0x0)
>
> System uptime in nanoseconds: 330571042058 last loaded kext at
>   122597264899: com.google.drivefs.filesystems.dfsfuse  37.0.8 (addr
>   0xffffff7f88d27000, size 102400) last unloaded kext at 208687925513:
>
> > usb.!UHostPacketFilter   1.0 (addr 0xffffff7f857fa000, size 24576) loaded kexts: com.google.drivefs.filesystems.dfsfuse  37.0.8
> >     com.symantec.ips.kext 9.0.2 com.symantec.nfm.kext 9.0.1
> >     com.symantec.internetSecurity.kext    9.0.3 com.symantec.SymXIPS  9.0.1
> >     !AUpstreamUserClient 3.6.8 @kext.AMDFramebuffer  3.0.8
> >     AudioAUUC    1.70 @kext.AMDRadeonX4000   3.0.8 @kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager 3.0.8
> >     !AGraphicsDevicePolicy   5.1.16 @AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics    5.1.16 @fileutil    20.036.15
> >     !AHV 1 |IOUserEthernet   1.0.1 |IO!BSerialManager    7.0.4f6
> >     pmtelemetry  1
> >     !APlatformEnabler    2.7.0d0
> >     AGPM 111.4.4
> >     X86PlatformShim  1.0.0
> >     !AMikeyHIDDriver 131
> >     !A!IHD5000Graphics   14.0.5 @Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0
> >     eficheck 1
> >     !AHDA    283.15
> >     !AMikeyDriver    283.15 @kext.AMD9000!C  3.0.8
> >     !AThunderboltIP  3.1.4
> >     !ALPC    3.1 |!ABCM5701Ethernet  10.3.5
> >     !ASMCLMU 212
> >     AirPort.BrcmNIC  1400.1.1
> >     !A!IFramebufferAzul  14.0.5
> >     !A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
> >     !AMCCSControl    1.11 @filesystems.autofs    3.0
> >     !AVirtIO 1.0 @filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5 @!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless  1.0.0d1 @BootCache  40
> >     @!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib  1.0.0
> >     @filesystems.apfs 1412.101.1 @private.KextAudit   1.0
> >     !ASDXC   1.7.7
> >     !AAHCIPort   341.0.2
> >     !AACPIButtons    6.1
> >     !ARTC    2.0
> >     !AHPET   1.8
> >     !ASMBIOS 2.1
> >     !AACPIEC 6.1
> >     !AAPIC   1.7 $!AImage4   1 @nke.applicationfirewall  303 $TMSafetyNet    8 @!ASystemPolicy   2.0.0 |EndpointSecurity 1
> >     @kext.AMDRadeonX4070HWLibs    1.0 @kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices  3.0.8
> >     !AGraphicsControl    5.1.16 |IOAVB!F 840.3
> >     !ASSE    1.0 @plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
> >     DspFuncLib   283.15 @kext.OSvKernDSPLib  529 @!AGPUWrangler  5.1.16 |IONDRVSupport   575.1
> >     !AHIDKeyboard    209
> >     !AHDA!C  283.15 |IOHDA!F 283.15 |IOEthernetAVB!C 1.1.0
> >     !ASMBusPCI   1.0.14d1 |IO80211!F 1200.12.2b1
> >     mDNSOffloadUserClient    1.0.1b8
> >     corecapture  1.0.4 |IOSkywalk!F  1 @kext.AMDSupport  3.0.8 @!AGraphicsDeviceControl  5.1.16 |IOAccelerator!F2    438.4.5
> >     |IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F 1.0.0
> >     X86PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
> >     IOPlatformPlugin!F   6.0.0d8
> >     !ASMBus!C    1.0.18d1 |IOGraphics!F  575.1
> >     !AThunderboltEDMSink 4.2.3 @kext.triggers    1.0 |Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.4f6 |IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.4f6
> >     |IO!BHost!CTransport  7.0.4f6 |IO!B!F 7.0.4f6 |IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.4f6
> >     usb.!UHub    1.2
> >     usb.networking   5.0.0
> >     usb.!UHostCompositeDevice    1.2 |IOAudio!F  300.2 @vecLib.kext  1.2.0 |IOSerial!F   11 |IOSurface   269.11 @filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext  1
> >     !AThunderboltDPInAdapter 6.2.6
> >     !AThunderboltDPOutAdapter    6.2.6
> >     !AThunderboltDPAdapter!F 6.2.6
> >     !AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter  2.5.4 |IOAHCIBlock!S    316.100.5
> >     !AThunderboltNHI 5.8.6 |IOThunderbolt!F  7.6.0 |IOAHCI!F 290.0.1
> >     usb.!UXHCIPCI    1.2
> >     usb.!UXHCI   1.2 |IOUSB!F    900.4.2
> >     !AEFINVRAM   2.1
> >     !AEFIRuntime 2.1 |IOSMBus!F  1.1 |IOHID!F    2.0.0 $quarantine   4 $sandbox  300.0 @kext.!AMatch 1.0.0d1
> >     DiskImages   493.0.0
> >     !AFDEKeyStore    28.30
> >     !AEffaceable!S   1.0
> >     !AKeyStore   2
> >     !UTDM    489.101.1 |IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice    422.101.1
> >     !ACredentialManager  1.0
> >     KernelRelayHost  1
> >     !ASEPManager 1.0.1
> >     IOSlaveProcessor 1 |IOTimeSync!F 840.3 |IONetworking!F   3.4 |IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.101.3 |IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F    422.101.1
> >     |IO!S!F   2.1 |IOUSBHost!F    1.2
> >     !UHostMergeProperties    1.2
> >     usb.!UCommon 1.0
> >     !ABusPower!C 1.0 |CoreAnalytics!F    1
> >     !AMobileFileIntegrity    1.0.5 @kext.CoreTrust   1 |IOReport!F   47
> >     !AACPIPlatform   6.1
> >     !ASMC    3.1.9
> >     watchdog 1 |IOPCI!F  2.9 |IOACPI!F   1.4 @kec.pthread    1 @kec.Libm 1 @kec.corecrypto   1.0

Comment: If you think it's being caused by Minecraft, try uninstalling it.

Comment: I don’t think it’s because of the Minecraft

Comment: You mentioned that it started when you installed Minecraft, so save all your game data and uninstall Minecraft, see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I have minecraft removed and surprisingly not sudden sleeps. Keep observing today and share how it goes...

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur thanks for editing. Fan's not working when PC in a sleep mode. Instead, it goes to a sleep mode after fan's intensive work. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out I was experiencing the issue ONLY when using Chrome browser, when I switched to Safari.

Then when I checked the version of the Chrome browser, I noticed it was having issues with automatic update.

[image]

[image]

Then I manually downloaded the latest version of the Chrome browser and don't have the issue anymore.

[image]